# Find the number of digits needed to express the number $f(10^6)-f(10^6-1)+f(10^6-2)-\cdots+f(2)-f(1)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> For each positive integer $n$, let $f(n)$ be the number of positive integers $k$ for which $k^{1000}$ has exactly $n$ digits.
>
> Find the number of digits needed to express the number $$f(10^6)-f(10^6-1)+f(10^6-2)-\cdots+f(2)-f(1)$$ in decimal notation.

This question needs to be solved without a calculator, but in the method I used below I have to use a calculator to show that $-3 < \log_{10}\left(\dfrac{1-10^{-\frac{1}{1000}}}{1+10^{-\frac{1}{1000}}}\right) < -2$. How can I solve this without a calculator?

**Attempt:**

Since $10^{m-1} \leq k^{1000} < 10^m$ if $k^{1000}$ has $m$ digits, it follows that $10^{\frac{m-1}{1000}} \leq k < 10^{\frac{m}{1000}}$. The number of such $k$ is $$\left\lceil 10^{\frac{m}{1000}}\right\rceil-\left\lceil 10^{\frac{m-1}{1000}}\right\rceil$$ and we have \begin{align*}S &= -\left(\left\lceil 10^{\frac{1}{1000}}\right\rceil-\left\lceil 10^{\frac{0}{1000}}\right\rceil\right)+\left(\left\lceil 10^{\frac{2}{1000}}\right\rceil-\left\lceil 10^{\frac{1}{1000}}\right\rceil\right)-\cdots+\left(\left\lceil 10^{\frac{10^6}{1000}}\right\rceil-\left\lceil 10^{\frac{10^6-1}{1000}}\right\rceil\right)\\&= 2\left(\left\lceil 10^{\frac{0}{1000}}\right\rceil+\left\lfloor 10^{\frac{2}{1000}}\right\rfloor+\cdots+\left\lceil 10^{\frac{10^6}{1000}}\right\rceil\right)-\left(\left(\left\lceil 10^{\frac{1}{1000}}\right\rceil+\left\lceil 10^{\frac{1}{1000}}\right\rceil\right)+\left(\left\lceil 10^{\frac{3}{1000}}\right\rceil+\left\lceil 10^{\frac{3}{1000}}\right\rceil\right)+\cdots+\left(\left\lceil 10^{\frac{10^6-1}{1000}}\right\rceil+\left\lceil 10^{\frac{10^6-1}{1000}}\right\rceil\right)\right).\end{align*} Taking away the floor and ceiling functions gives $$T = 2\left(10^{\frac{0}{1000}}+10^{\frac{2}{1000}}+\cdots+10^{\frac{10^6}{1000}}\right)-2\left(10^{\frac{1}{1000}}+10^{\frac{3}{1000}}+\cdots+10^{\frac{10^6-1}{1000}}\right)-10^{10^3}$$ and so \begin{align*}T &= 2\left(\dfrac{-10^{\frac{1}{1000} \cdot (10^6+1)}-1}{-10^{\frac{1}{1000}}-1}\right)-10^{10^3}.\end{align*} Note that $|T-S| \leq 10^6$. We can ignore the $1$ term to get \begin{align*}2\left(\dfrac{10^{\frac{1}{1000} \cdot (10^6+1)}}{10^{\frac{1}{1000}}+1}\right)-10^{10^3} &= 2\left(\dfrac{10^{\frac{1}{1000} \cdot (10^6+1)}}{10^{\frac{1}{1000}}(1+10^{-\frac{1}{1000}})}\right)-10^{10^3}\\&= 2\left(\dfrac{10^{10^3}}{1+10^{-\frac{1}{1000}}}\right)-10^{10^3}\\&= 10^{10^3}\left(\dfrac{2}{1+10^{-\frac{1}{1000}}}-1\right)\\&= 10^{10^3}\left(\dfrac{1-10^{-\frac{1}{1000}}}{1+10^{-\frac{1}{1000}}}\right).\end{align*} Note that $$-3 < \log_{10}\left(\dfrac{1-10^{-\frac{1}{1000}}}{1+10^{-\frac{1}{1000}}}\right) < -2,$$ so $T$ has $998$ digits.

Comment: Why did you get rid of all your work in the edit?

Comment: @infinitylord I thought it was too long to include in the question. I put it back.

Comment: In the inequality involving -2 and -3 you have $-2 < -3$, which isn't true. Did you mean to use absolute value or just get inequality backward?

Comment: @Χpẘ Yes, you are right. It was backwards.

Comment: In the first equation for $S$ you basically have $S=a_1-a_0+a_2-a_1+\dots+a_{999999}-a_{999998}+a_{1000000}-a_{999999}$. If I have this correctly, then $S=a_{1000000}-a_0$, because all the other terms cancel out. So $S=10^{1000}-1$. And the number of digits in $S$ would be 1000.

Comment: @Χpẘ There is also plus and minus on each two terms. It should be $-(a_1-a_0)+(a_2-1)-\cdots+(a_{10^6}-a_{10^6-1})$.

Comment: Ah, right. Saw that, but then forgot about it. Your answer makes a lot more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

***This took entirely too long*** and god I hope I made no blunders, but OP was nice enough to type out his question so I bothered.

Note that 
$$\frac{1-\gamma^{-x}}{1+\gamma^{-x}} \cdot \frac{\gamma^x}{\gamma^x} = \frac{\gamma^x-1}{\gamma^x+1}$$ To that end let $a = 10^{\frac{1}{1000}}$ and our inequality on one side is
$$-3 < \log_{10}(\frac{a-1}{a+1}) \\
10^{-3} < \frac{a-1}{a+1} \\
a+1 < 1000a-1000 \Rightarrow \frac{1001}{999} < a$$ Considering the other inequality we have with some steps now omitted
$$\frac{a-1}{a+1} < 10^-2 \Rightarrow 100a-100 < a+1 \\
99a < 101 \Rightarrow a < \frac{101}{99}$$So we are left with the inequality 
$$ \frac{1001}{999} < 10^\frac{1}{1000} < \frac{101}{99}$$ Which is true and kind of interesting, and makes me want to demonstrate that
$$\frac{10^n+1}{10^n-1} < 10^\frac{1}{10^n} < \frac{10^{n-1}+1}{10^{n-1}-1}$$ holds in the general case. The pattern is certainly quite suggestive. If we do the $\gamma$ trick above we're left with the nice-looking 
$$\frac{1+10^{-n}}{1-10^{-n}} < 10^{\frac{1}{10^n}} $$which conveniently has a nice Taylor series in $\ln$ so we have
$$2(10^{-n} + \frac{1}{3}\cdot 10^{-3n} + \frac{1}{5}\cdots ) < 
\frac{1}{10^n}\ln(10) \\
2(1 + \frac{1}{3}10^{-2n} + \frac{1}{5}10^{-4n} + \cdots) 
< \ln(10) $$
Noting that
$$\ln(10) = 2(\frac{9}{11}+\frac{1}{3}\frac{9}{11}^3 + \frac{1}{5}\frac{9}{11}^5 + \cdots) $$Which shows our left inequality is true on a term-by-term comparison. (edit: Tricky 1. You need to show that the sum of the first two terms in $\ln(10)$ are greater than the first two terms on the left when $n\geq 2$, which they are directly, then all the remaining terms on the left are smaller forever.) For the other inequality we will show (canceling the redundant factor of 2)
$$\frac{1}{10}(\frac{9}{11}+\frac{1}{3}\frac{9}{11}^3 + \frac{1}{5}\frac{9}{11}^5 + \cdots ) < 
1 + \frac{1}{3}10^{-2(n-1)}  + \frac{1}{5}10^{-4(n-1)} + \cdots \\
 \frac{9}{11}+\frac{1}{3}\frac{9}{11}^3 + \frac{1}{5}\frac{9}{11}^5 + \cdots 
< 10 < 10 + \frac{1}{3}10^{-2(n-1)+1}  + \frac{1}{5}10^{-4(n-1)+1} + \cdots
$$

Answer (score 0):

We need to evaluate $10^{\frac {-1}{1000}} \approx 0.9977$ by hand.  We have $\ln \left(10^{\frac {-1}{1000}}\right)=\frac {-1}{1000} \ln(10) \approx -0.0023$.  Maybe you know that $\ln(10) \approx 2.30$  Then $10^{\frac {-1}{1000}}=e^{\ln \left(10^{\frac {-1}{1000}}\right)}\approx 1-0.0023=0.9977$  Then you want $\log_{10} \frac {0.0023}{1.9977}\approx \log_{10}0.0015$ and you are there.